# How do I write an SQL query that will safely insert a record into a variable table name?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sql-injection

I have a function that inserts a record into a table. The name of the table needs to be a parameter of the function, and the column names are obtained dynamically. To guard against SQL Injection, I would like to use PostgreSQL's parameterized queries. Something like this:

```
function insert(tableName, val1, val2) {
    let qry =   `INSERT INTO $1 ($2, $3)
                VALUES ($4, $5)
                RETURNING id;`

    let values = [tableName, 'col1', 'col2', val1, val2]

    return db.query(qry, values);
}
```

While the `$n` substitution works great for values, it cannot be used for table or column identifiers.

From the [PostgreSQL documention](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html)

> Arguments to the SQL function are referenced in the function body using the syntax $n: $1 refers to the first argument, $2 to the second, and so on. If an argument is of a composite type, then the dot notation, e.g., $1.name, can be used to access attributes of the argument. The arguments can only be used as data values, not as identifiers

---

Compare this to the following code which works but seems to offer little protection against SQL injection.

(note the use of ECMA6 `${}` string substitution in place of parameter substitution)

```
function insert(tableName, val1, val2) {

    let values = ['col1', 'col2', val1, val2]
    let qry =   `INSERT INTO ${tableName} (${values[0]}, ${values[1]})
                VALUES ($3, $4)
                RETURNING id;`


    return db.query(qry, values);
}
```

Is there a way to allow parameterized queries that mitigates this? I'm hoping for something built into PostgreSQL or the Postgres library for Node, but I will accept any solid answer.

I'm running Node 9.4 and PostgreSQL 10

Comment: What driver are you using to do your SQL commands ?

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI I'm using node-postgres (https://node-postgres.com/features/queries). I haven't come across any alternatives.

Comment: You can use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), and its [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) for dynamically generating schema/table/column names ;) If it is of interest, I can publish it as an answer ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t Thank you. I took a look at the library and I think it will work better than just using pg. But I'm a little confused on how I would use it for the above problem. Under [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names), the first example shows how a column name can be inserted dynamically. Is this insertion something that is done by your library, or does the replacement happen on the Postgres side? Either way, if you want to write this up as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following parameters:

- `table` - table name
- `columns` - array of column names or an object with properties
- `values` - array of corresponding column values

then the simplest approach within [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) syntax is as follows:

```
function insert(table, columns, values) {
    const query = 'INSERT INTO ${table:name} (${columns:name}) VALUES(${values:csv})'; 
    return db.query(query, {table, columns, values});
}
```

or a shorter syntax:

```
function insert(table, columns, values) {
    const query = 'INSERT INTO ${table~} (${columns~}) VALUES(${values:csv})'; 
    return db.query(query, {table, columns, values});
}
```

See [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names), [CSV Filter](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#csv-filter).

And from version 7.5.0 it gets even simpler for dynamic objects:

```
function insert(table, obj) {
    const query = 'INSERT INTO ${table:name} (${obj:name}) VALUES(${obj:csv})'; 
    return db.query(query, {table, obj});
}
```

> Under [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names), the first example shows how a column name can be inserted dynamically. Is this insertion something that is done by your library, or does the replacement happen on the Postgres side?

PostgreSQL server does not allow dynamic SQL names, [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) implements it internally, providing safe escaping to protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the parameter to check the table name from a list of available tables before proceeding.

I'm not sure if there is an easier way to transfer the variables, but if you put the values into a temporary table, and call about procedure that takes the values from temp table, inserts those into dynamically selected table you should be fairly safe.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I follow (new to SQL). Is the idea that I somehow generate a brand new table with a query, then if that table is successfully generated, copy the inserted row into the actual table? Would this work for the dynamically generated column names as well?

Comment: No, the first procedure inserts the val1 and val2 into a temp table, and checks that the table name is in the list of and tables.  The second procedure takes those values from the temp table and inserts then into the variable table then deletes them from the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would like to suggest to Object-relational mapping (ORM) for this case scenario, and this is my personal recommendation and maybe this will help you

> here is a library link
>   [objection](http://vincit.github.io/.js/#introduction) which you can
>   use.

***Objection.js is built on an SQL query builder called knex.***

so then you can write a clean syntax

> here is very simple example

// `person` is an instance of `Person` model.

```
const movie = await person
  .$relatedQuery('movies')
  .insert({name: 'The room', awesomeness: 9001});

console.log('best movie ever was added');

insert into "Movie" ("name") values ('The room')
```

Comment: I like the idea of this, as I think it would work very well for what I wanted to do. However, the link you provided is dead. There is no GitHub page for the account referenced.

Comment: @BrianHVB  here is link [https://www.npmjs.com/package/objection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/objection)